# Contar registros consulta SQL Server y copiar resultado en celda excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

Actualmente por restricciones en mi empresa solo puedo usar Excel para realizar programas. No se nada sobre programación VBA en excel y necesito hacer una consulta a la BD SQL Server y que me copie el número de registros que ha encontrado en una celda Excel.

La consulta es la siguiente:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT  * FROM dbo_SQnet_Measures, ((dbo_SQnet_TestValues INNER JOIN dbo_SQnet_TestDefinitions ON dbo_SQnet_TestValues.MEASURE_DT = dbo_SQnet_TestDefinitions.LAST_CHECK) INNER JOIN dbo_SQnet_Users ON dbo_SQnet_TestValues.USR_CODE = dbo_SQnet_Users.REC_CODE) INNER JOIN dbo_SQnet_Locations ON dbo_SQnet_TestDefinitions.PARENT_CODE = dbo_SQnet_Locations.REC_CODE WHERE dbo_SQnet_TestDefinitions.LAST_CHECK = date() and dbo_SQnet_TestValues.MEASURE_DT = date()-1 and dbo_SQnet_TestValues in (4,5)"
```

Si me pudiese alguien echar una mano para empezar, lo agradeceria mucho.

Un slaudo y gracias :)

Comment: Quizás [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27385245/255257) (en inglés) te pueda ser de ayuda

Comment: Vas a tener que mirar en Internet cómo crear la configuración para conectarte a tu SQL server, y de ahí usar un objeto `Recordset` que te permita contar el nº de registros.

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomendaria echar un ojo a la libreria SpreadsheetLight, si trabajas en Visual Studio, no se si esta en mas plataformas, me ha costado 4 días pero la estoy sacando todo el potencial, es interesante.

Comment: Se aplaude la intención de responder. Te recomiendo leer [answer] pues, en mi opinión, tu respuesta carece del detalle suficiente, de acuerdo a los estándares de StackOverflow.